# Error on IDs in postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have a drop down list and i populate it with data from db , and while selecting the drop down list items , buttons will be dynamically generated depends on the selection .

But i encounter this error :

> could not be located or a different control is assigned to the same ID
>   after postback. If the ID is not assigned, explicitly set the ID
>   property of controls that raise postback events to avoid this error.

These are my codes :

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
          BindActivity();
        }

         if (dropListActivity.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
                PopulateButtons(Convert.ToInt32(dropListActivity.SelectedValue));
                StoryIcons();
       }      

    }
   protected void BindActivity()
        {
            dropListActivity.DataSource = daoActivity.GetAll();
            dropListActivity.DataTextField = "ActivityName";
            dropListActivity.DataValueField = "ActivityID";
            dropListActivity.DataBind();

            dropListActivity.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
            dropListActivity.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

PopulateButtons is too long so i just going to post half of it ( since i don't know if it is related )  .

```
  protected void PopulateButtons(int id)
    {
       // IList<ModelSQL.task> lol = daoTask.GetBasedOnKey(id);
        IList<ModelSQL.ActivityTask> actTask = daoActivityTask.GetBasedOnKey(id);
        foreach (ModelSQL.ActivityTask task in actTask)
        {

            if(task.GroupID == null)
             {
                ImageButton test = new ImageButton();
                 test.ImageUrl = daoTask.GetURL(id, task.taskID);
                 test.ToolTip = daoTask.GetTaskName(task.taskID);
                 test.Width = 100;
                 test.Height = 100;

                 test.Click += (source, e) =>
                 {
                     // Question(Convert.ToInt32(dropListActivity.SelectedValue),Convert.ToInt32(taskid.Text));
                     Session["activityID"] = dropListActivity.SelectedValue;
                     Session["taskID"] = daoTask.GetID(test.ToolTip , id);
                     Response.Redirect("DisplayQuestion.aspx");
                 };
                 Literal lc = new Literal();
                 lc.Text = "&nbsp;";
                 AddToPanels(test);
                 AddToPanels(lc);
                 i++;
             }                         
        } // end of foreach where groupid = null
```

i tried to assign the controls ID by

> test.ID = "name" + i.ToString ;

where the i will keep adding value every loop. ANd i also try

> test.ID = this.UniqueID + "name" + i.ToString ;

however it don't work .

Answer (score 0):

You have to recreate your dynamically created controls somewhere before calling Page.LoadViewState methods. Best place for this is Page_Init. Otherwise when page will try to load viewstate for those controls it wouldn't find they (because they still not have been created) and fails.

You may save DDL selected item value in the session for example and use session parameter as argument when you will call PopulateButtons from Page_Init

Comment: Sorry but i don't get what u meant

Comment: According [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx) page loads its viewstate and its controls viewstate somewhere before Page_Load event. Viewstate loads control-by-control, each control loads its viewstate and calls this process for its children. So when page starts loading viewstate, it tries to found all of its children, including dynamically added by you controls. But at this moment those controls doesn't exist, so page raises exception.

Comment: but that doesn't happen to me before , i always do the above to populate buttons ..